# In android, How to post photo from sd-card to tumblr?

Tags: android, tumblr

Unable to post photo which is captured by device camera and which is picked up from gallery to tumblr... Please Suggest some way...
I have tried it using multipart entity as well as using namevaluepair.
Also I attached with http request file format data, byte[], base64 format data and URLEncoder format data.

Foolowing solutions i have tried :

```
// #1
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("type", new StringBody("photo"));
ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(byteArray, "image.jpg");
reqEntity.addPart("data", bab);
httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);



// #2
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "photo"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caption", "caption"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", file);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


//#3
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "photo"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caption", "caption"));
nameValuePairs.add((NameValuePair) new ByteArrayUploadData(byteArray));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Please Suggest...

Comment: Have you done it.can you please share your solution. I have the same problem.